# Unable to access web application that's running in container built on docker

Tags: python, docker, uwsgi

I have a simple python program that does the following

**identitydock.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello Docker!\n'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

My Dockerfile is as follows

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.4

RUN groupadd -r uwsgi && useradd -r -g uwsgi uwsgi
RUN pip install Flask==0.10.1 uWSGI==2.0.8
WORKDIR /app
COPY app /app
COPY cmd.sh /

EXPOSE 9090 9191
USER uwsgi

CMD ["/cmd.sh"]
```

my **cmd.sh** is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [ "$ENV" = 'DEV' ]; then
  echo "Running Development Server"
  exec python "identidock.py"
else
  echo "Running Production Server"
  exec uwsgi --http 0.0.0.0:9090 --wsgi-file /app/identidock.py \
             --callable app --stats 0.0.0.0:9191
fi
```

A simple web page that should return 'hello docker' for some reason does not work when I run using docker.

The commands I gave to run the application:

> docker build -t identidock .
>
> docker run -d -p 5000:5000 identidock

When I do curl localhost:5000 I get the following message

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5000: Connection refused

May I know if there is an issue with my docker configuration?

I am using the following docker version on MacOSX

> Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e

Reference source 
https://github.com/using-docker/using_docker_in_dev

**Edit -1**

On docker ps -a , the container status shows 'UP'

on docker logs CONTAINER_ID, i get the following logs

```
Running Production Server
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.8 (64bit) on [Thu Jul  6 02:04:04 2017] ***
compiled with version: 4.9.2 on 06 July 2017 02:03:16
os: Linux-4.4.74-boot2docker #1 SMP Mon Jun 26 18:01:14 UTC 2017
nodename: 323e6ff35d0d
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /app
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
your processes number limit is 1048576
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1048576
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uWSGI http bound on 0.0.0.0:9090 fd 4
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:45710 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 3.4.6 (default, Jun 21 2017, 18:32:49)  [GCC 4.9.2]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x1bd9640
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 145536 bytes (142 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x1bd9640 pid: 1 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 6, cores: 1)
*** Stats server enabled on 0.0.0.0:9191 fd: 13 ***
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 7)
```

Comment: Why do you need `cmd.sh`? What is that doing?

Comment: @cricket_007, added cmd.sh

Comment: Is container alive when you try to access it? See its status in `docker ps -a`. Also see its output with: `docker logs <container-id>`

Comment: @Robert, added logs here

Comment: try to go inside the container and see if `flask` server is running. `docker exec -it <container_name> /bin/bash`

Comment: @Prith, I did the command specified and did flask --version but I get flask command not found

Comment: ah so looks like your server isnt even up! you should try to get it up and running within the container, then you can try to do it using commands in the `dockerfile`. `pip install flask` for starters and manually run the file by doing `python appname.py` and see if it runs there or not and then curl from a different terminal window.

Comment: @Prith, I am inside this terminal and I am unable to do pip install/apt-get install flask . I get permission denied. Also sudo command is not found

Comment: you might want to start over with a bare-bones python container without the `cmd.sh` file you have and just try to set up everything inside the container, once that works just put the commands in a script and run that in the `dockerfile`

Comment: @Prith, I apologize, but I am can't comprehend your instruction. So do you want me to remove the lines 'USER uwsgi, CMD ["/cmd.sh"]' from dockerfile and do docker build and then docker run -p 5000:5000. I tried that but the container exits. May I know what you meant? thanks

Comment: follow this tutorial http://containertutorials.com/docker-compose/flask-simple-app.html

Answer (score 2):

You're connecting port 5000 on the host to port 5000 on the container. But you don't have anything running on port 5000, you have something running on 9090 and 9091. so try `docker run -d -p 5000:9090 identidock` or `docker run -d -p 5000:9091 identidock`

Comment: Nope, still the same error when doing curl localhost:5000

Comment: ```
$ docker run -d -p 5000:9090 identidock
...
$ docker logs 99
Running Production Server
...
failed to open python file /app/identidock.py
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
...-- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
...--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
... ```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are reading the book [*Developing and Deploying Software with Containers*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491915765). I met similar problem and only to find that I didn't follow the steps completely.

According the codes and commands you gives, the author is tying to replace the original Flask WebServer (bind port 5000 in container with port 5000 in host machine) with uWSGI (bind port 9090 in container with 9090 in host machine). **But `docker run -d -p 5000:5000 identidock` indicates that you insist on binding port 5000 in container with port 5000 in host machine, so you can't access uWSGI that is running in the container.**

**The command `EXPOSE 9090 9191` used in `dockerfile` only assigns ports for the container, so you need to allocate ports for the host machine.**

By the way, the author recommend to use `-P` to make host machine allocate available ports randomly, so you don't need to assign ports like `-p 9090:9090 -p 9191:9191` manually.